# Is it possible to put a string resource in EXTRA_TEXT

Tags: android, string, share, android-studio, android-resources

I have this line that I share the text "text to share"

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text to share");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

but I want to share a @string no "text to share"

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `getResources()` method to get access to your resources and then use `getString()`:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getResources().getString(R.string.text_to_share));
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```